# In R how can I find the number of connections I have in a given dataframe and produce a variable representing it?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

So I currently have a dataframe which represents a social network like follows:

```
id age  id1    id2   id3   
01  14  02      05    03        
02  23  01      05    03        
03  52  04      01    02        
04  41  03                      
05  32  01      02
```

Ideally I would like a new data frame like the following:

```
id age  id1    id2   id3   Connections
01  14  02      05    03        3
02  23  01      05    03        3
03  52  04      01    02        3
04  41  03                      1
05  32  01      02              2
```

With a new variable the represents the number of connections the "id" has. As of now I currently have a code like follows:

```
links <- df
links <- as.matrix(links)
links <- as.data.frame(rbind(links[,c(1,3)], links[,c(1,4)]), links[,c(1,5)])
head(links)

library(igraph)
g = graph.data.frame(links)
m = as.matrix(get.adjacency(g))
m
pmax(rowSums(m), colSums(m))
```

Which gives me:

```
 1  2  3  4  5 NA 
 3  3  3  1  2  3
```

How can I then incorporate this into the dataframe to create the "Connections" variable? Ideally my other data contains up to 50 connections so I would like an easier way in which I don't have to recreate a dataframe.

Comment: Maybe? `df$connections <- rowSums(!is.na(df[, c("id1", "id2", "id3")]))` or more flexible: `df$connections <- rowSums(!is.na(df[, grepl("id[0-9]+", names(df)]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick `tidyverse` way is to reshape the data into a long shape, add up how many non-`NA` values each ID has, and reshape back to wide.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = key, value = val, -id, -age) %>%
  group_by(id, age) %>%
  mutate(connections = sum(!is.na(val))) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, age [5]
#>   id      age key   val   connections
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <int>
#> 1 01       14 id1   02              3
#> 2 02       23 id1   01              3
#> 3 03       52 id1   04              3
#> 4 04       41 id1   03              1
#> 5 05       32 id1   01              2
#> 6 01       14 id2   05              3

df %>%
  gather(key = key, value = val, -id, -age) %>%
  group_by(id, age) %>%
  mutate(connections = sum(!is.na(val))) %>%
  spread(key = key, value = val)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   id, age [5]
#>   id      age connections id1   id2   id3  
#>   <chr> <dbl>       <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 01       14           3 02    05    03   
#> 2 02       23           3 01    05    03   
#> 3 03       52           3 04    01    02   
#> 4 04       41           1 03    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 05       32           2 01    02    <NA>
```

But I wouldn't consider your first approach wrong. Since you're working with a network, it makes sense to use network analysis tools and calculate the degree of each node, same as the number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
# Toy data
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), 
                age = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                id2 = c(1, 2, 3, NA), 
                id3 = c(1,2, NA, NA))

df$Connections = df %>%
  select(-id, -age) %>% # Remove unnecessary columns
  apply(1, function(row) {
    binary_row = as.numeric(!is.na(row)) # Convert each column to binary
    sum(binary_row) # Return connection count
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

- First, using `regex` we determine the columns corresponding to connections

  ```
  # here connections columns must contain the pattern "id"+digit(s)
  connectionsNames <- grepl("id\\d+", names(df), perl = TRUE)
  ```
- Then we use `rowSums` to create the new column

  ```
  df$connections <- sum(connectionsNames) - rowSums(is.na(df))
  ```
- Here the result

  ```
  df
    id age id1 id2 id3 connections
  1  1   1   1   1   1           3
  2  2   1   2   2   2           3
  3  3   1   3   3  NA           2
  4  4   1   4  NA  NA           1
  ```